# Upload file from host server ("http://some_address/some_image.jpg")

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

'm trying to upload file that is hosted, using direct link to it:

```
WebElement browseBtn = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".upload>input"));
browseBtn.sendKeys("http://some_address/some_image.jpg");
```

I know it works fine with local files (i.e. "C:\Dir\file.file"). But when i "sendkeys" http address, i got

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: path is not absolute: http://some_address/some_image.jpg
```

What to do with when we need to upload file from host server?
(link to file is valid.)

Comment: setKey should have absolute path similar to the one you are trying localy. ie C:\some_address\some_image.jpg

Comment: But how about "http..." path? When i do it manually - it works. Is it impossible to do with Selenium?